# Bootstrap datetimepicker setting seconds to 0

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Problem: I get output eg "2019-10-14T08:12:48" and i want seconds to to be 00 ie "2019-10-14T08:12:00"

I can't take out the ss from the format, as i'm sending to a controller that only accepts LocalDataTime and need seconds included.

I'm currently using the below code and dependency to add a date time picker functionality to an input filed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-datetimepicker</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Javascript code

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  //set up datetime picker so it loads on first click
  $('#time-input').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
    showMeridian: true,
    startDate: '+1h',
    minuteStep: 1,
  });

  //on click for input to toggle the datetimepicker
  $('#time-input').click(function(event) {
    $('#time-input').datetimepicker();
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="time-input" type="text" class="form-control" 
   data-date-format="yyyy-mm-ddTHH:ii:ss">
```

Comment: What you want **second to 0**?

Comment: @jishansiddique sorry i submitted by mistake and had more to include in the question. yes seconds to be 0 when exiting the datetimepicker

Comment: if you share minimal, verifiable code which replicates this issue, it'll be easier to help

Comment: @jishansiddique sorry for late reply https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js you can see the whole code